# Set default value of HTML5 date input field with node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html, datepicker

I am hoping to bind the default value I generated in moment to the date and time input field. I tried  directly binding it to the value attributes. But none of it seems to work. Is there a way to make it work?
Also, how to bind the time input field as well?

```
<aside class="widget">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepick"></p>
</aside>
```

Comment: where's the moment code? Is it outputting a string or unix time or something into html? ie using `format()`? Should know better than to post question without code

Answer (score 0):

for datepicker type should be date, and to set default value check with the below one

```
<input type="date" value="2013-01-08">
```